# Firebase - OnWrite called everytime node updated

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

There's a problem with my onWrite() cloud function. I have the following database structure:

```
"data" : {
    "pushId" : {
      "date_time" : "date time",
      "status" : true
    }
```

The function works fine by sending a push notification whenever a new pushId is inserted into "data", however it also sends a push notification when a single child node is updated. For example whenever the status is changed to false it send another push notification.

Is there anyway to only send push notifications once, when a new pushId is inserted into "data" and never again for that pushId?

Thank you all for you help!

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform some work only once for a write to a particular location in the database, you will need a strategy for flagging that the work has already happened.  Then you need to check that flag on future function invocations to skip that work.  The easiest thing to do is write a flag value back to the same location of the database, then check the value of that flag for each invocation to make sure it was not previously set.

Comment: I use the event parameter to check if the "status" is true before executing the push notification. Works great if status changes but not when the "date_time" gets updated.